# Algorithm/Data Structure -- Find max difference between consecutive numbers in an array that are less than a given number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array, int[] arr, I want to find int[] dist such that dist[k] is the largest distance between 2 consecutive numbers less than k. Hopefully, this should perform in faster than O(n log n).

For instance, if my array is `[3, 8, 5, 6, 9]`, dist[6] should be 2 because 3 is at position 0 and 5 is at position 2, and thus the distance traveled is 2 - 0 = 2.

Note that "consecutive" here does not necessarily mean `x` and `x + 1` or `arr[x]` and `arr[x+1]`, only that if `arr[i]` and arr[j] are consecutive, there is no `m` between `i` and `j` such that `arr[m]` is less than the given threshold.

If this was asking for a minimum or a sum, I could easily apply RMQ or a Fenwick Tree. With this, I'm not sure how to approach it, but I suspect it could be an extension of RMQ or Fenwick, I just don't know how.

Comment: Your description is inconsistent - you seem to keep swapping between indices and array values. E.g. shouldn't "Find max difference between" in the title be "max *distance*"? Also, shouldn't "between 2 consecutive numbers less than k" in the first paragraph be "less than *arr[k]*"?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Ah I see; I was mislead by his subsequent use of `k` in the 3rd paragraph to indicate an arbitrary index. But yes I realise now that the `k` in `dist[k]` is the input number.

Comment: My mistake, I will edit my post for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look up in `O(log n)` time for arbitrary `k` (or `O(1)` time for pre-listed `k`) with `O(n log n)` preprocessing:

```
input     [3, 8, 10, 5, 6,  9]
sorted    [3, 5,  6, 8, 9, 10]
indexes   [0, 3,  4, 1, 5,  2]

highest consecutive difference so far, low to high:
  on each iteration of index, find the nearest lower and higher neighbours;
  if the new diff splits the previous best interval, pick the larger one

  i 0 (<5)  - N/A
  i 3 (<6)  - (0)   => diff 3, interval (0,3)
  i 4 (<8)  - (3)   => diff 3, 4 has no effect on best interval
  i 1 (<9)  - (0,3) => diff 2 (3-1), 1 splits the previous interval, new: (1,3)
  i 5 (<10) - (4)   => diff 2, 5 has no effect on the best interval
  i 2 (<11) - (1,3) => diff 1, 2 splits the previous interval

lookup table: [N/A, 3, 3, 2,  2,  1]
k:            [  5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Example with duplicates (presented in a comment from thebenman below:

```
[1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5
0, 2, 5, 1, 3, 6, 4

i [2]   -> 2 (0,2)
i [5]   -> 3 (2,5)
// duplicates must be considered together
i [1,3] -> 2 (3,5) split the previous interval
i [6]   -> 2 (3,5) 6 has no effect on previous interval
i [4]   -> 1 (3,4) or (4,5)
```

Comment: I do not think this will work for i/p `[1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4]` and for `dist[5]` if you sort the array.

Comment: @thebenman addressed in the answer. Great observation, thanks!

Comment: According to OP's definition `dist[5]` can't be `(2, 5)` as that range has a number(3) that is less than the threshold.

Comment: @thebenman I think you misunderstood my example. `i  [5]` means, "we are now considering the index, 5, in our sorted index list." That one corresponds with k = 2+1 = 3, meaning the largest consecutive distance for numbers lower than 3.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on bucket sort.
Given n numbers, you find min (the smallest) and max (the largest) in O(n).
If the numbers were evenly distributed the difference, denoted d_bar, would be (max-min) / (n -1).
Create buckets of size d_bar from min to max and assign every number to its bucket. This too takes O(n) with O(n) numbers in any given bucket. And O(n) numbers in all the buckets cumulatively.
For each bucket find its min and max and discard all other numbers. This is done in O(n) too.
Now you are left with a set of k<=n numbers that are sorted and in O(n) you can the maximum difference.
It is easy to prove that this is also the maximum difference of the original set. And as you see it is found in O(n) time (and space)